# How do you start to play a bag paused?

Tags: ros, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am playing a rosbag through a launch file (that also contains a python script and rviz) and it works fine.

However, rosbag play starts to run after some time  (of course). I can pause it by pressing the space bar and reinitiate again. Great.

My question is, is there a way to specify that the playing of the rosbag should start paused? (and wait for my space bar pressing)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374771/how-do-you-start-to-play-a-bag-paused?/) by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2021-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the answer!

use `--pause`

```
<launch>
   <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag_play" output="screen" required="true"
         args="--pause /opt/robomaker/datasources/mybaggroup_1/myS3prefix/log_0.bag"/>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) with karma: 170 on 2021-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1